# Confusion over Java generic method type inference

Tags: java, wildcard, type-inference, generic-type-argument

The sample method is given below:

```
static <T> void doSomething(List<? super T> list1, List<? extends T> list2) { }
```

I am wondering what type will be inferred in this situation and by what logic. Let's say I am calling this method like this:

```
doSomething(new ArrayList<Object>(), new ArrayList<String>());
```

Would *T* type evaluate as *Object* or *String*?

Comment: The call does not bind `T` to a specific class. Here is a [small demo](http://ideone.com/uGge45) that expanded your code to demonstrate this point.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight You could post that as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This call does not bind `T` to a specific class. Java does not need to know the exact `T` because of type erasure implementation of the generics. As long as the types that you pass are consistent with the declaration, the code should compile; in your case, lists of `Object` and `String` are consistent with the declaration.

Let's expand your code a little so that we could force binding of `T` to a specific type. Perhaps the easiest way to do it is to pass `Class<T>`, like this:

```
static <T> void doSomething(List<? super T> list1, List<? extends T> list2, Class<T> cl) {
    System.out.println(cl);
}
```

Now let us try calling `doSomething` with `String.class` and with `Object.class`:

```
doSomething(new ArrayList<Object>(), new ArrayList<String>(), Object.class);
doSomething(new ArrayList<Object>(), new ArrayList<String>(), String.class);
```

Both calls successfully compile, producing the output

```
class java.lang.Object
class java.lang.String
```

[Demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/uGge45)

Comment: Another interesting example is with more class hierarchy `doSomething(new ArrayList<Object>(), new ArrayList<Integer>(), Number.class);`. This shows that `T` does not actually have to match the type of either list. It simply must be "between" (inclusive) them.